# Displaying a div relative to its id in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have in my view

```js
$(document).ready(function()
  {
    $(".view_proposal").click(function(e)
    {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(".proposal").fadeOut(500);
      var id = $(this).attr('id');
      $("details-"+id).fadeIn(500);
    });
  });
```

```css
.proposal
{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#"><li class="list-group-item view_proposal" id="1"><strong>Alen</strong> requesting at <strong>10000</strong></li></a>
<a href="#"><li class="list-group-item view_proposal" id="2"><strong>Alen2</strong> requesting at <strong>20000</strong></li></a>


<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      Proposal Details
    </div>
    
      <div class="panel-body proposal" id="details-1">
        BLA BLA BLA
      </div>
  
  <div class="panel-body proposal" id="details-2">
        BLA BLA BLA BLAB adskofojd;lff
      </div>

  </div>
```

When I click on `view_proposal` anchor tag they do fadeOut the previous result but don't show their related id div. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Probably you're missing the `#`? It should be `$("#details-"+id).fadeIn(500);` not `$("details-"+id).fadeIn(500);`?

Comment: You need a `#` at the start of the selector. `$("#details-"+id).fadeIn(500);`

Comment: Also, `$(this).attr('id')` is not good code. Use `this.id` instead.

Comment: Oh god! One silly mistake! Thank you guys! I am learning jquery it will take a bit of time to get used to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to append `#` to selector.

```
$("#details-"+id).fadeIn(500);
```

Comment: Thank you :) just took steps to learn jquery